# Keeping ListenAndServe up on GoClipse

Tags: go, goclipse

I'm beginning with Go http/net programming, and with ListenAndServe i'm not getting a template rendered because when i run the main.go file it prints the Listening line and exits with state 0 on Eclipse, this is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, err := template.ParseFiles("templates/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, err.Error())
    }
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", nil)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Listening on port: 3000")
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil) 
}
```

There's any way on GoClipse to keep the program up?, or there's something i'm missing here?

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Always use `fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))`, this question literaly gets asked 5 times a week, something else is listening on port 3000 most likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot @OneOfOne, that solved the problem, and something else was listening on port 3000 indeed, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just moving my comment since I couldn't find any of the other questions (I know I answered this last week but I can't find it).

Rule #1 of Go, always check for errors.

For `http.ListenAndServe` usually it's common practice to use `fmt.Println(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))` or `log.Println`.